# how to debug jquery plugins collision

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I have 2 jquery script: "Yii-EchMultiselect" and "datePicker".

When I use both plugins on the same page, the date-picker doesnt work.
How can I find why?
I know both plugins use jquery_min.js but i guess there is a collision in other shared resources.
Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Check the console for errors to see what exactly the problem is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks...the thing is there are no errors..

Comment: If the problem is so reproducible that you can simply add them both to your document and it'll appear, you should be able to creat a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for us (and describe the error, if it's not apparent). That way we will be able to see how you've referenced the two plugins, how you're using them, and investigate the outcome.

Comment: Do you actually reference `jquery_min.js` twice? Is one of those references after a reference to one of the plugins? Because you should only have to include it once, and if you did, you've overwritten the value of `$` and any plugins that it had been extended with.

Comment: I found that no script is loaded twice, but when i use both plugins jquery-ui-min.js is loaded and when the multiselect is not loaded the date-picker is working...i cant put fiddle because it's in php script HTML_OPTIONS: i.e. 
$this->widget('ext.EchMultiselect.EchMultiselect', array(
                            'model' => $model,

Comment: Go to the page you are having problems with and view source. There you can see how the <script> tags are actually being created (which is what we need to see to be able to help you.) I would think it's rare to have a plugin not work due to a conflict without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used both of these widgets in the same view.

Make sure each widget has a distinct DOM id set in htmlOptions.  I've had this problem before. Also please post your code.